# How do I send wood to a ceremonial bonfire?

Tags: northgard

One of the recent updates to Northgard (PC via Steam) added a new area called 'Ceremonial Bonfire'. Its description reads:

> The construction of the bonfire is an occasion for a huge celebration. Everyone can contribute by sending wood!

How do I send wood?

- I can't assign villagers of any type to the bonfire
- The trade post doesn't show that I can set up a "trade route" to the bonfire.

[image: Screenshot of map zone with ceremonial bonfire]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a random event, just like the dwarves gemstone and the myrkalf iron events. When this event happens, you will be able to send wood to it via trading post.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I only got the event once and then never saw it again. Am I missing something?